# How to set a thumbnail to a video file on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, video, vlc-media-player, thumbnails

I have a mkv file and I would like to set a thumbnail. I would like this thumbnail to be an image of a random moment of this video, as Windows did for my other videos. If I am not clear enough, I’ll explain again. I don’t want to chose the thumbnail myself, I want Windows to automatically set the thumbnail. At the moment, the icon is the VLC cone.

Comment: Your question is still open. You should ***accept*** your answer that you made yourself that had the link. It might be a good idea to transcribe the steps from the video by chance the video is ever taken down your answer still helps others

Answer (score 0):

The reason the icon is displaying as VLC, is because that is the default application to run that file.

To change this navigate to Options -> View -> Uncheck: Display file icon on thumbnails

[image: as in this image]

Next, if the file preview is small it will show the icon so you need to enlarge the file preview by navigating to View -> Layout.

[image: as in this image]

or as a shortcut, use ctrl + mouse scroll

You want to also uncheck: Always show icons never thumbnails.

[image: here]

You might want to clear thumbnail cache:

1. Open your File Explorer. Click This PC.
2. Right-click the drive where
   you Windows is installed.
3. Select Properties. Then select Disk
   Cleanup.
4. Check the box next to Thumbnails.  Make sure all other
   options are unchecked.

[image: see here]

Comment: It didn’t change anything. There is something wrong with this file, because all my other mkv files are displaying a thumbnail...

Comment: @valfur03 have you checked after i edited my answer?

Comment: I think so because I saw your answer after you edited it

Comment: @valfur03 try again, iv'e made another edit

Comment: no, still the vlc cone

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/Sg5-nfI7oyA. You have to download Icaros and click on activate thumbnails once you opened it.